# A nilpotent matrix is similar to a strictly upper triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $n>1$ and $A\in M_n(F).$ Suppose $A$ is nilpotent. Prove that $A$ is similar to a strictly upper triangular matrix by induction on $n$.

How should I do this? I don't know how to use the assumption to relate it to the definition of similarity of matrices that's why  I'm stuck.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to get $S$?

Comment: Cayley-Hamilton is not proved to us yet so we can't use it. My teacher hinted that this involves eigenvalues and can be shown that 0 is an eigenvalue of $A$

Comment: Show that every nilpotent matrix has an eigenvector (with eigenvalue zero).